# Error updating azure web app bot application settings using azure cli

Tags: botframework, azure-cli

I have deployed a web app bot in Azure. I am trying to update it's application settings using Azure Cli. Please find the commands below:

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g <ResourceGroup> -n <ResourceName> --subscription <AZsubscription> --settings SettingToChange=SettingValue
```

The command fails saying that it was not able to find Resource under the Resource Group mentioned in the command.

I think the above command is for azure web app and not for web app bot. What command should I use to update application settings for web app bot ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the above command is for azure web app and not for web app bot. What command should I use to update application settings for web app bot ?

No, the command `az webapp config appsettings set` should work for the azure web app bot, I test it on my side, it works fine. I think you need to make sure you have passed the correct parameters.

My specific test command:

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g joywebapp -n joywebbot --subscription <subscription id> --settings testkey=test1
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Yes I was able to update the app settings. Actually, the name of the app service was different than the bot name, as it was created using az create bot command.